# Remove default styling in Jquery Mobile Header / Footer

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to put an image which is wrapped in a link into my footer of my jQuery mobile page however when I do this it transforms into a button. How can I stop this from happening and get just the image only with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done easily.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/UZwpj/

It can do it by adding this attribute:

```
    data-enhance="false"
```

to the header, content, footer container.

This also needs to be turned in the app loading phase:

```
    $(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;
    });
```

***Initialize it before jquery-mobile.js is initialized (look at the example below).***

More about this can be found in my personal blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, just search for a chapter called: **Methods of markup enhancement prevention**